# exporting Powershell Script to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

We are getting ready to merge our AD with another. We have about 300 computers that I'm trying to match up with who uses them so the accounts and home folders migrate correctly, and I'm trying to think of the most efficient way to get this information.

We have everyone in an inventory system (Filemaker) (and will be implementing SCCM once we migrate (thank god) ) but we had a few errors when we did our first test batch. Im looking for something I can push out through group policy (possibly?) that will give me the computer name, logged in account, and them email it to me.

So far this is what I have.

```
[System.Environment]::UserName
[System.Environment]::UserDomainName
[System.Environment]::MachineName
Out-File T:\TEST.txt
```

But the output is blank. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Also is there a way to have this run on multiple computers but write to the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"$env:USERNAME,$env:USERDOMAIN,$env:COMPUTERNAME" | Out-File 'T:\test.txt'
```

will write the name and domain of the currently logged-in user as well as the hostname of the local computer to the file `T:\test.txt`.

Using a single file may cause conflicts due to concurrent write attempts, though. It's better to use one file per computer, like this:

```
"$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" | Out-File "T:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt"
```

Run it as a logon script (or from a logon script), e.g. like this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "\\%USERDNSDOMAIN\netlogon\your.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name | Out-File C:\outdir\machinelist.txt -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8`

will get you all machine names, unless you have them already. Either way, use your list of machines in

`$MachineList = Get-Content -Path c:\outdir\machinelist.txt; 
foreach ($Machine in $MachineList){
    ($Machine + ": " + @(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Machine -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem)[0].UserName) | Out-File "C:\outdir\result.txt" -Append
}`

If you change the destination directory to somewhere that all computers have access to, it can run on multiple computers. It won't email it to you but you can just grab it.

Comment: This assumes RSAT or Active Directory Powershell module installed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pipe those properties into the file like..

```
[System.Environment]::UserName, [System.Environment]::UserDomainName, [System.Environment]::MachineName | Out-File T:\Test.txt
```